# how to send changed cells to server in ag-grid

Tags: node.js, ag-grid

I'am making a new project with ag-grid. I've worked out an example where I can load data from a database into the grid. this works ! Now what I want to add is when a user changes a cell value the grid needs to send that changed value to the server and update the grid.

is there anyway how I can do this I can't seem to find any good examples for this.

this is my index.js

```
import {Grid} from 'ag-grid-community';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';

import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";

const gridOptions = {

    rowModelType: 'serverSide',

    columnDefs: [
        {field: 'athlete'},
        {field: 'country', rowGroup: true, hide: true, editable: true},
        {field: 'sport', rowGroup: true, hide: true},
        {field: 'year', filter: 'number', filterParams: {newRowsAction: 'keep'}},
        {field: 'gold', aggFunc: 'sum', editable: true},
        {field: 'silver', aggFunc: 'sum'},
        {field: 'bronze', aggFunc: 'sum'},
    ],

    defaultColDef: {
        sortable: true,
        editable: true
    }

    // debug: true,
    // cacheBlockSize: 20,
    // maxBlocksInCache: 3,
    // purgeClosedRowNodes: true,
    // maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests: 2,
    // blockLoadDebounceMillis: 1000
};

const gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
new Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

const datasource = {
    getRows(params) {
         console.log('test',JSON.stringify(params.request, null, 1));

         fetch('./olympicWinners/', {
             method: 'post',
             body: JSON.stringify(params.request),
             headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
         })
         .then(httpResponse => httpResponse.json())
         .then(response => {
             params.successCallback(response.rows, response.lastRow);
         })
         .catch(error => {
             console.error(error);
             params.failCallback();
         })
    }
};

gridOptions.api.setServerSideDatasource(datasource);
```

server.js

```
  import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackConfig from '../webpack.config.js';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import OlympicWinnersService from './olympicWinnersService';

const app = express();
app.use(webpackMiddleware(webpack(webpackConfig)));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/olympicWinners', function (req, res) {
    OlympicWinnersService.getData(req.body, (rows, lastRow) => {
        res.json({rows: rows, lastRow: lastRow});
    });
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Started on localhost:4000');
});
```

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the server about changes on `onCellEditingStopped` event:

```
const gridOptions = {
  ... ,
  onCellEditingStopped: function (event) {
    console.log("ask the server to update changed data in back end", event);
    let data = {rowIndex: event.rowIndex, id: event.data.id, col: event.column.colId, value: event.value}
    fetch(...).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
      console.log("server is updated, now we can refetch the data if we want.");
      // gridOptions.api.purgeServerSideCache();
    });
  }
}
```

Normally `ag grid` updates the cached data on client, and you should only update it on server. But sometimes you need to get the fresh data from the server, You can do it with `gridOptions.api.purgeServerSideCache();`. it clears the cache and ask the server for new datas.

[Live Demo](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/PoNjXPG?editors=1010)

Comment: thank you very much for your input I tried to implement it into my code but I failed to do it can you help me a hand ? I will update my Question with more code

Comment: what's this syntax you used: `app.updateData(...)` ? shouldn't you first create an api like: `app.post(/updateOlympicWinners)` to update the values? and contact with this api in your front end? (something like the api you wrote for getting the winners.) (sorry if i get it wrong. i did never see such syntax in express from before.)

Comment: thats you code from your life demo `app.updateData(...)` I tried to implement haha. I updated my code to the original code I had. I get the data from the database to fill my grid. but I want to try to send changes from front end to backend this is something i always struggle with and don't know how to do it. I am also very new to react and express thanks in regards :)

Comment: @user14182997 just `add an api for updateOlympicWinners` in express and `contact the server using fetch` like the answer. (note that the live demo is not an actual server. it's a fake server for mocking. ignore the demo. just use `onCellEditingStopped` and send the datas to server using `fetch`.) .i don't want to be mean, but this question is about `ag-grid` (an extension). using extensions without knowing the basic stuffs (express / api / how should front end contact to back end) just makes your life harder. i suggest to first create a simple todo app to understand mern stack, then try this.